# I can't write into my created json file, but I can print out what needs to be written

Tags: python, database

I want to extract data from a database and put it into separate JSON files. I can use the print command to print out what I want, but I can't write it into the file. Here's the code:

```py
import sqlite3

db_path = 'D:\\PyCharm\\Projekte\\Vivia_Medikamente\\database-Kopie-Kopie.db'
db_connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
db_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM articles;')
found_data = db_cursor.fetchall()

JSONnumber = 0

while JSONnumber < 299:
    DrugName = str(found_data[JSONnumber][4])
    JSONcontent = str(found_data[JSONnumber][7])
    f = open(DrugName + '.json', "w")
    f.write(JSONcontent)
    f.close()
    JSONnumber = JSONnumber + 1

print("done")
```

This is the error I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm/Projekte/Vivia_Medikamente/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    f.write(JSONcontent)
  File "C:\Users\Bennett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2081' in position 225: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've tried to change the file to a .txt file, but that did not help.

Comment: The error message refers to a line of code `f.write(str(found_data[JSONnumber][7]))` that is not in the code you posted.  It's very hard to help when you don't post your real code...

Comment: sorry, I changed it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UnicodeEncodeError%3A+%27charmap%27+codec+can%27t+encode+character

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is an encoding issue when writing the JSON content to the file.
To resolve this issue, you can try specifying a different encoding when opening the file, such as 'utf-8'. Here's an updated version of your code that uses `utf-8` encoding:

```py
import sqlite3

db_path = 'D:\\PyCharm\\Projekte\\Vivia_Medikamente\\database-Kopie-Kopie.db'
db_connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
db_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM articles;')
found_data = db_cursor.fetchall()

JSONnumber = 0

while JSONnumber < 299:
    DrugName = str(found_data[JSONnumber][4])
    JSONcontent = str(found_data[JSONnumber][7])
    with open(DrugName + '.json', "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(JSONcontent)
    JSONnumber = JSONnumber + 1

print("done")
```

In this updated code, the `open()` function now includes the `encoding='utf-8'` parameter, which specifies the desired encoding for the file. Using the `with` statement ensures that the file is properly closed after writing.

If your JSON cannot be encoded in `utf-8`, you may need to consider alternative approaches, such as escaping or you might need to convert the characters before writing the file.

Comment: All three of your answers so far here today appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting quality, non-AI content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: Exactly what kind of **JSON cannot be encoded in UTF-8**?